# How to show notifications to user when he logs in using asp.net

Tags: c#

I am trying to create notification in asp.net. that is when admin login and sends a message to client or user that message should be shown to user as a notification when user logs in using his credentials.

```
namespace seramailService
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        System.Timers.Timer createOrderTimer;

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
       public void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            createOrderTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            createOrderTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(GetMail);
            createOrderTimer.Interval = 500;
            createOrderTimer.Enabled = true;
            createOrderTimer.AutoReset = true;
            createOrderTimer.Start();
        }

        public void GetMail(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
            NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("ram.b2012@gmail.com", "Password");
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add("ram.b2012@gmail.com");
            msg.Subject = "Welcome Ram..";

            msg.Body = "You Have Successfully Entered to Sera's World!!!";
            msg.From = new MailAddress("ram.b2012@gmail.com"); // Your Email Id
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            SmtpClient client1 = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 465);
            client.Credentials = cred;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried examples using signalIR and windows services as above but it is not working and i want to show notification as facebook notification.and i tried below code but it is not working and this is not what i needed..please help me to create notification in asp.net.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you tried _anything_ so far to solve your problem? This is not a good way to ask. Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: http://www.google.com

Comment: Iam new to development and I have tried using signal IR and auto notification using windows service but iam not getting what exactly i needed.Please help me to show notification like facebook when user logs in..

Answer (score -1):

To do this you have to manage it from your application.